# Exact match over decimal values

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform an exact match over decimal values.

I have submitted two applications , for first application with annual salary as 99999868.10 and the other as 99999868.99.
When I do a query for 99999868 or I search 99999868.10 it returns me both the data , whereas I expect it to return only the exact match for it

The query I am executing is :

```
GET index/_search
{"query": {
   "term": {
      "Annual Salary": {
        "value": "99999868"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Share index mapping as well. Use `GET index/_mapping` to get mapping.

Comment: "AnnualSalary" : { 
  "type" : "float"
}

Answer (score 0):

Change mapping of salary field to numeric type and re index data

Numeric type reference : - `https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/number.html`

Answer (score 0):

use match_phrase and let me know. Actually, it will solve your problem.